# Build arduino with windows command line

Tags: arduino-uno, led, arduino-ide, compile

Can someone explain, step by step, along with all software I must use for using Windows command prompt to build an Arduino sketch (.ino file )?

I've followed [these steps](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37813.45) but I can't.

Comment: See the examples at the end of [**the link that Federico gave**](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc) eg example only:
Compile and upload a sketch to an Arduino Nano, with an Atmega168 CPU, connected on port /dev/ttyACM0:
   arduino --board arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega168 --port /dev/ttyACM0 --upload /path/to/sketch/sketch.ino

Comment: You said "I can't": can you clarify what you tried, what you expected andwhat you got?

Answer (score 4):

The command line interface of the Arduino IDE is described in this document

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc

For example, this command will compile and upload the Blink example to my Arduino Leonardo

```
./arduino --upload --board arduino:avr:leonardo --port /dev/ttyACM0 --verbose examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
```

Foot note: with IDE 1.6.0, there is an experimental version of the IDE for recent MacOSXs. It doesn't yet support the command line. If you need the command line on Mac, use the recommended version. This will be fixed with 1.6.1